# Evaluating the integral $\int (x^2+3)e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral:

$$\int_0^1 (x^2+3)e^{-x}dx$$

Here is my work:

$u= (x^2+3)$

$du=2x dx$

$dv= e^{-x}$

$v=-e^{-x}$

Plugging into the integration by parts formula

$(x^2+3)(-e^{-x}) - \int_0^1 2xe^{-x}$

How do I evaluate the integral on the right side?:

$$\int_0^1 2xe^{-x}$$

Edit: Okay so I was told to do integration by parts again so here are my new values:

$u=2x$

$du=2dx$

$dv=-e^{-x}$

$v=e^{-x}$

However I don't know how to properly plug this in. Do I just replace the integral with $uv-\int_0^1 vdu$?

Would this be right:

$$(x^2+3)(-e^{-x}) - (2x)(e^{-x}) - \int_0^1 2e^{-x} dx$$

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: Make integration by part twice !

Comment: Okay so I get $u=2x$, $du=2dx$, $dv=-e^{-x}$, and $v=e^{-x}$. I don't know how to plug this $uv-\int vdu$ into my formula which I already have.

Comment: Each integration by parts brings the degree of the thing in front of $e^{-x}$ down by one. If we were integrating $x^4e^{-x}$ we would integrate by parts four times.

Comment: Differentiate $(ax^2+bx+c)e^{-x}$. Then compare coefficients.

Comment: I updated my work, would that be correct?

Answer (score 1):

**An other way**

The antiderivate is of the form $$(ax^2+bx+c)e^{-x}.$$
Then,

$$\big((ax^2+bx+c)e^{-x}\big)'=(x^2+3)e^{-x}\implies (-ax^2+(2a-b)x+b-c)e^{-x}$$
$$\implies \begin{cases}a=-1\\2a-b=0\\ b-c=3\end{cases}\implies (a,b,c)=(-1,-2,-5).$$